# make install can't find aclocal

Tags: makefile, autotools, configure

I'm trying to compile a code to run in parallel on a supercomputer. I know that others have compiled this code to run on the same computer, but for some reason I am having trouble even when using the same methodology as them. For now I'm just trying to compile the code to run in serial as that should be easier to troubleshoot.

*configure* seems to work correctly.
However *make install* returns the following:

```
> make install

    CDPATH="${ZSH_VERSION+.}:" && cd .. && /bin/sh /home1/username123/code123/config/missing aclocal-1.13 -I ./config -I /home1/username123/code123/build-tools/aclocal -I /usr/local/share/aclocal
    aclocal-1.13: error: couldn't open directory '/usr/local/share/aclocal': No such file or directory
    Makefile:534: recipe for target '../aclocal.m4' failed
    make: *** [../aclocal.m4] Error 1
```

aclocal is indeed not located at /usr/local/share/aclocal, it is located at /usr/bin/aclocal - but as /usr/bin is in my path, I don't understand why the location is an issue.

Comment: How did you get the code onto the supercomputer in the first place?  What do you do before `make install`?  It is somewhat surprising that `make` is looking for such a file in the first place -- it is used only for maintaining the project's Autotools-based build system, and should not be necessary for building or installing the project itself.

Comment: I copied the source code onto the supercomputer, then "configure" (with default settings for the purpose of easy troubleshooting), and then "make install".

When I originally tried compiling the code (including additional libraries and  MPI), I received some odd errors regarding git and libtools which also didn't seem to make sense in the context of building & installing.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not specific enough, but it's enough for me to say that what you *should* do is copy **the distribution tarball** to the target computer, unpack it there, change to the package directory, and then proceed with `configure` and `make`.  Additionally, be sure that extraction of the `tar` file preserves the timestamps within (this is the default for every `tar` I have experience with).

Comment: It may also help to tell `configure` to `--disable-maintainer-mode`, but not all `configure` scripts support this.

Comment: I tried copying over the tarball to the supercomputer and unpacking it there. That fixed the issue, the code compiled correctly. I did not understand Autotool's reliance on time stamps. Thank you for your help @JohnBollinger !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been made clear in comments on the question, the problem was that the project sources were copied onto the target system in a way that failed to preserve their original timestamps.  The Autotools, through `make`, use file timestamps to determine which files are out of date, and in particular, `Autools`-generated `Makefile`s contain rules for rebuilding the build system itself that can be triggered this way.

It is not ordinarily necessary or desirable to rebuild an Autotools project's build system, except in conjunction with actually performing maintenance on it.  It is often the case, in fact, that the necessary support for that is not available locally.  To avoid the build system thinking that it needs to rebuild itself, it is important to preserve the file timestamps from the distribution archive.  For some packages, it also works to pass the `--disable-maintainer-mode` argument to the `configure` script, but by no means do all Autotools `configure` scripts support that.

The archive extraction tools for the typical archive formats in which Autotools-based packages are distributed do, by default, preserve timestamps when unpacking, so the ordinary procedure of

1. unpack the archive on the target system (*e.g.* `tar xzf foo-1.2.3.tar.gz`)
2. change to the unpacked source directory (*e.g.* `cd foo-1.2.3`)
3. `configure; make; make install`

normally does the right thing.  Substituting something else for (1), however, such as copying the unpacked source tree from somewhere else, may cause the package to think it needs to rebuild the build system.  If that works correctly then it's no big deal, but it is not uncommon that it doesn't.  That's what happened here, and following the standard procedure described above solved the problem.